# Netty: Listen on several addresses / ports with a single ServerBootstrap

Tags: java, netty

I currently have no idea how to listen with netty on multiple addresses / ports. I want to build a little HTTP Server which serves an special application. I need to run it on several addresses (like IPv4 and IPv6) and ports (443 / 80).

For each listener I want to use the same handlers. My current code looks like this:

```
public void run() {

    EventLoopGroup bossGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();
    EventLoopGroup workerGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    try {

        ServerBootstrap bootstrap = new ServerBootstrap();
        bootstrap.option(ChannelOption.SO_BACKLOG, 1024);

        bootstrap.group(bossGroup, workerGroup)
            .childOption(ChannelOption.ALLOCATOR, PooledByteBufAllocator.DEFAULT)
            .channel(NioServerSocketChannel.class)
            .childHandler(new ApplicationServerInitializer());

        Channel channel = bootstrap.bind(this.socketAddress).sync().channel();

        logger.info("Started HTTP Server on {}:{}", this.socketAddress.getHostName(), this.socketAddress.getPort());

        channel.closeFuture().sync();

    } catch(Throwable throwable) {
        logger.error("An error occurred while starting the HTTP- Server", throwable);
    } finally {
        workerGroup.shutdownGracefully();
        bossGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just call `bind(...)` multiple times.

```
List<ChannelFuture> futures = new ArrayList<>();
futures.add(bootstrap.bind(this.socketAddress(IPV4, 80)));
futures.add(bootstrap.bind(this.socketAddress(IPV4, 443)));
futures.add(bootstrap.bind(this.socketAddress(IPV6, 80)));
futures.add(bootstrap.bind(this.socketAddress(IPV6, 443)));

for (ChannelFuture f: futures) {
    f.sync();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I'm using Netty 5.0.0.Alpha2 and there, boostrap.bind(..) returns a ChannelFuture, so I can't call there bind(..) again. So if I do this in a loop, how should I close all the created Channels with `channel.closeFuture().sync();` while this function is a blocking one?

Comment: @user3641396 As far as I can see, the loop ist just to prevent the exit of the program. It starts blocking at the fist future in the list, but if you shutdown the ServerBootstrap, the channels begin closing. The loop ensures, that all of them are closed.